# How can I remove/hide formula if cell is blank?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

It's me again, your old pal.

I'm trying to get the latest date from 2 cells(please see example below) when COL B and COL C is 0 or blank it's still showing `12/30/1899 00:00:00` on COL D.

The formula I'm currently using:

```
=iferror(max(ARRAYFORMULA(B2:C2)))
```

It's all dynamic

```
B2                     C2               D2

Finance date           Project date     Max date
01/01/2020             01/05/2020       01/05/2020 01:00:35
(BLANK)                (BLANK)          12/30/1899 00:00:00 < (I want to show blank here)
```

What's the formula if COL B and COL C are blank to not run formula or show a blank?

Comment: `=IF(OR(B2="",C2=""),...)` where `...` is your formula

Comment: Thanks so much, brah! Helped out alot

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use `=IFERROR()` in this case since the `=MAX()` function will return 0 when both cells are empty, instead of returning an error.

Some of the possible solutions:

1. `=IF(OR(B2="", C2=""), "", MAX(B2:C2))`
2. `=IF(MAX(B2:C2)=0, "", MAX(B2:C2))`

Happy brogramming!

#### Reference

- [IF function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en)
- [OR function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093306?hl=en)
- [MAX function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094013?hl=en)
- [IFERROR function](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en)